# how to Find Template Name that has been used while creating a new Site Collection

Tags: 2007, development, site-collection, site-template

I have like tens of custom Site definitions, so when I try to create a new site collection I select a template name, let say "ABCD 2020 DEVELOPMENT ISSUE SOLVED" and create a new site based on this template.

when I try to get Template name of same site I just created I get something like this "STSabcsdsjhsd" , i tried following code to get it.

```
    public void GetSiteTemplate(string siteUrl)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            textBox3.Text = web.WebTemplate.ToString(); // output = "STSxcvmcxv2020"
            textBox4.Text = web.WebTemplateId.ToString(); // output = "100016"
            textBox2.Text = web.Configuration.ToString(); // output = "3"
        }
    }
```

Now I can't figure out how can I find out the Template Name that I used to create this site at first place, Programmatically

**Edit**

**How can I find Title of a Configuration using its Configuration saved in WEBTEMP***.xml file unless there is a better way to get it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's even a more elegant way than this, but this should work:

```
string siteUrl = "http://yoursiteurl";
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                foreach (SPWebTemplate template in site.GetCustomWebTemplates(uint.Parse("1033")))// or GetWebTemplates
                {
                    if (template.ID == web.WebTemplateId || template.Name == web.WebTemplate)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Template in use " + template.Title);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: +1, but I tried it your way and I tried it by going through "SPWebTemplateCollection" but its giving null :S

Comment: GetWebTemplates method worked for me, ta