# Getting Web Template using Configuration ID

Tags: development, site-collection, site-template

I am able to get Web template by checking its ID, but we have ten's of web configurations within a web template

so in short we have loads of web template id's with different configurations and Title.

In this question I find out how to find web template ID

[Get Web Template Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/how-to-find-template-name-that-has-been-used-while-creating-a-new-site-collectio/42551#42551)

**But I want to get web template by Configuration ID,  not just Web.WEBTemplateID**

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                foreach (SPWebTemplate template in site.GetWebTemplates(uint.Parse("1033")))
                {
                    if (template.ID == web.WebTemplateId || template.Name == web.WebTemplate)
                    {
                         //it gives me first or maybe last web template with id let say "10023" but i want to filter them with configuration id
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code worked for me :)

```
  try
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            foreach (SPWebTemplate template in site.GetWebTemplates(uint.Parse("1033")))
            {
                if (web.WebTemplate + "#" + web.Configuration.ToString() == template.Name &&
                    template.ID == web.WebTemplateId)
                {
                    tbTemplateCategory.Text = template.DisplayCategory;
                    tbTemplateTitle.Text = template.Title;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)